# How to change flex order upon window resize?

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

Please help me model this into css. I have three components as below.
[image]

When the width of the window shrinks below 1000px. The flex order should change as in the following picture.
[image]

Comment: Have a look into media queries; SO isn't a code writing service, we can't do the work for you if you don't provide examples you've already tried.

Comment: I'd also offer that CSS-Grid would be a better option here **but** you will still need media queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need have a main container, that contains each three components. So your html should be organized as following:

```
<div class="main-container">
   <div class="component1"></div>
   <div class="component2"></div>
   <div class="component3"></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.main-component {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.component1, 
.component2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
}

.component3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

@media(max-width: 1000px)
{
  .component1,
  .component2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

The '.main-component' is our flex-box. Component 1 and 2 stays side by side, because they have `width: 50%`. Component 3 stays below, because he has `width: 100%`. The media query `max-width: 1000px` provides the flex order change when the width of the window shrinks below 1000px.

working demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/hfkcdv1t/

Comment: Through all those downvotes I've secured, your answer helped a lot and was precise to the point. Thanks again.